# Rename file as computer serial number

Tags: command-line, scripts

Is it possible to rename a file to computer's serial number via terminal shell/script.

Example: I have a file at `/home/ladmin/Documents/ExampleFile123.txt` and I want to rename it as `PCSerial_Example123.txt`.

I am able to get the PC Serial Number with:

```
sudo dmidecode -s system-serial-number
```

But I don't know how to automate/script it to have a one liner code/command.

Comment: I like to save entire file and include this in my backup script. `sudo dmidecode > $FULLPATH/dmidecode_bios_$FN.txt` I set a path to a folder where I store that type of info FULLPATH and a FN for several variables: `TODAY="$(/bin/date '+%Y-%m-%d')"` & 
`SYSVER="$(lsb_release -cs)"` & 
`FN=$TODAY"-"$SYSVER"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `dmidecode` command to get the serial number, where the exact command is `sudo dmidecode -s system-serial-number`. You can then use command substitution `$()` to use this expression inside the filename, like this:

```
mv -nv /home/ladmin/Documents/ExampleFile123.txt "/home/ladmin/Documents/$(sudo dmidecode -s system-serial-number)_Example123.txt"
```

*Please note that the serial number string may not be unique (for instance, SuperMicro servers sometimes always return `0123456789`, and RaspBerry Pis return no serial number at all). The `-nv` option to the move command ensures that a file is not overwritten.*

Comment: `mv -nv` can be used for protection against overwriting. `-n` will not rename the file if a file with the same name exists, and `-v` will show verbose output, that is, no output if no renaming is done, else it will show the renaming.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to rename files successfully, thanks.